# Angular Elements in Dialogflow

Tags: angular, dialogflow-es

I have been using rich responses like custom payloads for a while in Dialogflow but still not feeling a good interactive user experience with it. I wonder If using Angular Elements would solve this problem but it seems that sending HTML elements as response is not possible in Dialogflow.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: kindly show what you have tried so far.

Comment: the truth is I don't have anything to try since custom payloads have a JSON-like syntax to use and do not know html/javascript